# Изменить индекс массива значением другого массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach, for

Имеется массив объектов в localStorage, планирую создать количество div равное длине массива в localStorage, сделать из них массив, а затем по очереди записать данные в заголовок, картинки, ссылки и т.д. где первый элемент нового массива его свойство заголовок (textContent) берется из первого элемента массива взятого из localStorage (свойства объекта), второй элемент заголовок (textContent) массива берется из второго элемента (свойства объекта) и т.д. Планировал сделать одним единым циклом, чтобы не нагружать память и затем одной операцией записать на страницу, но затык на элементарной ситуации, которую не пойму как решить. Цикл переписывает **все** элементы первого массива **первым** значением массива (свойства объекта) из localStorage и т.д. В итоге возвращается массив с одинаковыми свойствами равными последнему индексу в localStorage. Как заставить брать свойства по порядку, индекс одного равен индексу другого?

```
// получаем длину массива и записываем в переменную
let favoritesLength = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`favoritesArr`)).length;
let favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`favoritesArr`));

// создаем количество дивов равное длине массива

let divFavor = document.querySelector('.favor').cloneNode(true); // клонированием
let d = document.createElement(`div`); // либо новый
    let arr = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < favoritesLength; index++) {
        arr.push(d); 
        arr[index].textContent = favorites[index].name; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создали только один `div` и все время добавляете в массив ссылку на него.

```
let favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`favoritesArr`));
let favoritesLength = favorites.length;

//let d = document.createElement(`div`); // либо новый
let arr = [];
for (let index = 0; index < favoritesLength; index++) {
  arr.push(document.createElement(`div`)); 
  arr[index].textContent = favorites[index].name; 
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Сергей Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.